# Azure Service Fabric - selective update of service parameters with Powershell?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have an Azure Service Fabric Cluster with several apps and services.  Some of the services contain up to 50 parameters (meaning the `Key:Value` pairs that you would see if you clicked on the Details tab of a given service in Service Fabric Explorer).

I need to update **just one** of these parameters out of a list of 50+.  One of my devs is under the impression that the only way you can make a change to one of these parameters is run a Powershell script that contains **all** of the service's parameters within the script.  In other words, if you try to run the script with *only* the parameter you want to update, you will erase all the other parameters.

Question 1: is there truly no way to update just one Service Fabric service parameter without including all of the existing parameters in the script?

Question 2: are there any tools/templates out there that help you build the Powershell script to make these kinds of changes in Service Fabric?

Comment: Are you talking about parameters from `Settings.xml`?

Comment: @OlegKarasik no, not the `settings.xml` under `PackageRoot/Config`.  When you build a Service Fabric solution in Visual Studio, there will be a folder under the Service Fabric section of the solution called `ApplicationParameters`.  In this folder there will be a number of XML files - when you first build the solution, it contains 3 by default called `Cloud.xml`, `Local.1Node.xml`, and `Local.5Node.xml`.  These files are used to enter and store key:value pairs related to your application. Which xml file you use depends on how you're deploying (to the cloud, or to a local instance of SFC).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to update the parameter without performing _application upgrade_ or _remote/create new application_. If you are using Azure DevOps (VSTS) there are set of actions integration with publish profiles (`Cloud.xml` etc.) and can auto-increment version of you the application before the actual deployment (as mentioned by @DiegoMendes). If by some reason the process should be done manually through PowerShell scripts then I suggest you to try the solution by @SteppingRazor.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no way to update just one parameter.

Service fabric has the concept of packages (Code, Config, Data) where you can change one of then without changing the others, in your case, you have to change the Config only, but each change generates a new version, and the change must include all the data, because you are replacing the previous version, not amending it.

The "right way" (best) to release SF apps is using a CI/CD tool like VSTS to automate these changes, not running scripts by hand, because it is hard to keep track of changes and soon or later, small changes like the one you want to do, become a huge pain.

If these releases were controlled using a CD tool, like VSTS, Octopus, Jenkins, you would just change the values and trigger a new release.

Answer (score 2):

Once the application is deployed to the cluster it is possible to connect to the cluster and retrieve list of the current parameters, running `Get-ServiceFabricApplication` command.

So it can be achieved by custom `PowerShell` script. During the deploy you can gather existing parameter values and combine with new parameters. Then you pass combined parameters and deploy the application. Should not be that hard to do.

That's the one way I can think of. And I don't think there is some built in functionality for this. And yes the developer is right you always have to provide all parameters.

Comment: I was probably a little unclear in my post - I do know how to do the change via Powershell - just was looking for a way to do it without having to include all parameters.  Thanks for your answer though, it's valuable info for those who don't know about `Get-ServiceFabricApplication`